# Do UK citizens have a right to legal advice?

Tags: united-kingdom, human-rights

As a British citizen: If I can't afford to pay a solicitor to get legal advice, am I entitled to free legal advice from the government?

Comment: Under what circumstances? The answers differ based on the situation.

Comment: In certain conditions yes, see https://www.gov.uk/legal-aid, but in general I presume not.  I'm not sure in which cases this is a "legal right" and in which cases it's simply a service that the government provides.

Comment: Also, it varies by jurisdiction (England and Wales, Scotland, and Northern Ireland)

Comment: Yes you are entitled to legal advice. You are also entitled to pay for it.

Comment: There is a right to a fair trial, under article six of the European convention on human rights. In some circumstances it might be argued that if you are forced to go through a trial without an opportunity to get advice that you need then this right is infringed.

Comment: It depends on the circumstances. For example if you have been arrested you are entitled to it, and you can ask for it at any time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the circumstances, see [here](https://www.gov.uk/legal-aid).

> You’ll usually need to show that:
>
> - your case is eligible for legal aid
> - the problem is serious
> - you can’t afford to pay for legal costs